How to use mlogit for models where there are no choice specific variables
Suppose one wants to model choice of product among two cellphones and two colors, but cellphone 1 only comes in red or green while cellphone 2 only comes in blue or black. So there is a nesting in the choices. However, there are no choice-specific variables. If using mlogit for this, is the code below correct?
mlogit(choice ~ 1 | gender + age, data = ddataset, 
        nests = nests)

Where ddataset is formatted in long format with each participant having 4 rows (one for each choice) but gender and age have the same value for each of those rows (since they belong to the same person).
Note: By choice-specific variables, I mean that there are no pre-selection features that vary per option. For example, we choice-specific option may be price of the product. We can make this vary per respondent. E.g., for respondent 1 it may be that cellphone 1 costs 100 but cellphone 2 costs 150. This may be different for respondent 2.

Could you explain what a "choice-specific variable" is?

A good approach to solving such problems is to simulate some choice data with a utility model where you know the ground truth and see if you can recover it with your statistical model.
